# minimizing event data shown on the Jquery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to minimalize the data shown on a given day (w/event) in the calendar?  I know this seems like a weird request. Specifically I want to remove the title and start time...  Essentially if I could just have a css class for days with events, or I am fine with the current "bubble" it shows now just with out the extra info.  http://www.seattledesigndistrict.com/events/ is the calendar I am working with right now.  It's pulling data from a wordpress custom post type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next ',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },

    weekMode: 'liquid',
    height: 250,
    events: [
        <?php
            $myEvents = get_posts('post_type=event&orderby=title&order=ASC&numberposts=-1');
            $eventString = '';
            foreach($myEvents as $event){
                $eventString .= '{ title: \''.$event->post_title.'\',';
                $eventDate = get_post_meta($event->ID,'event_date',true);
                $dateParts = explode('-',$eventDate);
                $startTime = get_post_meta($event->ID,'starttime',true);
                if($startTime != ''){
                    $startTimeArray = explode(':',$startTime);
                    $makeStart = mktime($startTimeArray[0],$startTimeArray[1],0,$dateParts[1],$dateParts[2],$dateParts[0]);
                } else {
                    $makeStart = mktime(12,0,0,$dateParts[1],$dateParts[2],$dateParts[0]);
                }
                $displayDate = date('c',$makeStart);
                $eventString .= 'start: \''.$displayDate.'\',';
                $endTime = get_post_meta($event->ID,'endtime',true);
                if($endTime != ''){
                    $endTimeArray = explode(':',$endTime);
                    $makeEnd = mktime($endTimeArray[0],$endTimeArray[1],0,$dateParts[1],$dateParts[2],$dateParts[0]);
                    $displayEndDate = date('c',$makeEnd);
                    $eventString .= 'end: \''.$displayEndDate.'\',';
                }
                $eventString .= 'url: \''.$event->guid.'\',';
                $eventString .= 'allDay: false},';                  
            }
            $eventString  = substr($eventString, 0, -1);
            echo $eventString;
        ?>
    ]
})
});
</script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `eventRender` hook as described in the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/).  The hook provides you access to the element used to render the event.  The below code removes the text, leaving the box as is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
// your other code here
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).
          remove(".fc-event-time"). // the time span in a full calendar event
          remove(".fc-event-title"); // the title span in a full calendar event
    }
})
});
</script>
```